# How to access the dictionary from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
$(function() {
  $.get("https://firststep-2016.appspot.com/Map", function() {
    var dataSet = [{
      "lat": 35.964642464800001,
      "lng": 127.8646424648
    }, {
      "lat": 36.964642464800001,
      "lng": 127.8546305428
    }, {
      "lat": 36.969020999999998,
      "lng": 127.8694266
    }, {
      "lat": 36.968989999999998,
      "lng": 127.86950950000001
    }, {
      "lat": 34.064642464800002,
      "lng": 122.1646424648
    }, {
      "lat": 36.9685652824,
      "lng": 127.8693936768
    }, {
      "lat": 38.064642464800002,
      "lng": 123.1646424648
    }, {
      "lat": 38.064642464800002,
      "lng": 127.6646424648
    }];

    var option = {
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      position: location
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), option);

    $.each(dataSet, function(i, value) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(value[i]["lat"], value[i]["lng"]),
        map: map,
        draggable: false
      });

    });
  });
});
```

I want to access the key values "lat" and "lng". However, the following error occurs.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Comment: If you put a `debugger;` within your `$.each`, what is the value of `value[i]`?

Comment: Always check with the documentation as well [**jQuery each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

`value` is an `object` with `lat` and `lng` properties, like so:

```
$.each(dataSet,function(i,value){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(value["lat"],value["lng"]),
    map: map,
    draggable: false}); 

});
```

No need for `value[i]["lat"]`

Alternatively (but unnecessarily) you could access the same object given by `value` using `dataSet[i]` (and hence use `dataSet[i]["lat"]` and `dataSet[i]["lng"]`). I pointed that out simply for clarity sake so hopefully you could see what's going on.

Finally, `jQuery's` utility `$.each` method is unnecessary. You're dealing with an array here, just use a `forEach`:

```
dataSet.forEach(function(latLng) {
   (new google.maps.Marker({
     position:latLng, //see LatLngLiteral (below)
     map:map,
     //draggable is false by default, no need to specify draggable:false
   });
});
```

[LatLng Literal](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal)

Comment: tkank you. your solution very useful to me. but i meet unother problem.

Comment: Ajax is not receiving data from python.

Comment: This is my python class. class getLatLng(webapp2.RequestHandler):
 def get(self):
  db = connect_to_cloudsql()
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute("""select latitude,longitude from User;""")
  
  dic={}
  array_list=[]
  for row in cursor.fetchall():
   dic['lat']=float(row[0])
   dic['lng']=float(row[1])
   array_list.append(dic.copy())
  
  latLng=json.dumps(array_list)
  db.close()
  
  return latLng

Comment: @jihyemoon - ask another question, I've answered this one.

Comment: $.ajax({
  type:"get",
  url:"https://firststep-2016.appspot.com/getLatLng",
  dataType: "json",
  cache:false,
  success:function(latLng){
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
   zoom: 11,
   center:latLng[0]
   });  
   
   $.each(latLng,function(i,value){
    new google.maps.Marker({
    position: value,
    map: map
    }); 
   });
  }
 });  it is ajax.